# How do I set an element of a doubly nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested

I run the following lines in the Python interpreter and I get:

```
>>> s = [[0]*5]*5
>>> s
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> s[2][4] = 1
>>> s
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

However I want the last line to be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Why is this not happening?

Comment: `s = [[0]*5 for _ in range(5)]` otherwise you end up with five copies of the same inner list.